Bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(S)\neq S$ for $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ infinite and co-infinite
Is there a bijection $f:\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\N\to\N$ such that $f(S)\neq S$ whenever $S\subseteq \N$ is infinite and $\N\setminus S$ is infinite?

You need to learn the language of group actions and orbit decomposition. Your question is then: is there an action of $G=\mathbf{Z}$ on a infinite countable set such that the only invariant subsets are finite or cofinite. This means that some cofinite subset is a single orbit. Obviously this can be done for every infinite countable $G$.

Concerning $G=\mathbf{Z}$, since you are asking many question, have in mind that every permutation of a set has a cycle decomposition, and that when one "sees" the cycle decomposition, the answer to this kind of question is kind of obvious (rather than focussing on the enumeration of the set on which you act).

@YCor: one doesn’t need to learn about group actions or orbit decompositions for this question — it’s much easier than that…

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I'm not saying this. But thinking in these terms makes the question somewhat trivial. (Cycle decomposition of a permutation is, anyway, a very basic fact.)

Sorry, I thought the question was about $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$ in the previous version of my answer. Let me fix this: Choose any bijection $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ and let $f(n) = g^{-1}(g(n)+1)$.

More generally, following exactly the same approach as in the answer to your previous question: The $f$ for which there exist $S$ which are infinite and co-infinite and satisfy $f(S)=S$ are exactly those with infinitely many orbits or more than two infinite orbits.


at least two infinite orbits, of course

